# Do not start loop if error message is returned in API request

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a API Call for some live information. When there is no live information it will return:

> error = "No live games found";

Otherwise it will return different information like `hometeam`, `awayteam`, `score` and so on.

In my loop I'm adding these information to an array `arrayEuropa`. The problem is if the API request return the error message it should not add anything to the `arrayEuropa`.

How can I obtain this?

I've tried different things that works when it return the error message, but crashed when there is no error message.

Here is my code:

```
NSDictionary* headers4 = @{@"X-Mashape-Authorization": @"key"};
NSDictionary* parameters4 = @{};

UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response4 = [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest* request4) {
    [request4 setUrl:@"https://willjw-statsfc-competitions.p.mashape.com/live.json?key=APIKEY&competition=europa-league&timezone=Europe%2FLondon"];
    
    [request4 setHeaders:headers4];
    [request4 setParameters:parameters4];
}] asJson];


NSData* rawBody4 = [response4 rawBody];
results4 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawBody4 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

for (int i = 0; i <= results4.count-1; i++)
{
    
    
    NSString *homeTeam = [[results4 valueForKey:@"homeshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *awayTeam = [[results4 valueForKey:@"awayshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *time = [[results4 valueForKey:@"statusshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *homeScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[results4 valueForKey:@"runningscore"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *awayScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[results4 valueForKey:@"runningscore"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectAtIndex:1]];
    
    
    [arrayEuropa addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:homeTeam,@"hometeam", awayTeam,@"awayteam", time, @"time", homeScore, @"homescore", awayScore, @"awayscore", nil]];
    
}
```

Comment: Where are you checking for the error field in the response?

Comment: I'm not checking now i've tried with if(results[@"error"]), but does not work probably

Comment: Can you log the contents of `results4` for success and error and add that to the question please.

Comment: If the response is all JSON, then should you look for [results4 valueForKey:@"error"] to see if there is an error?

Comment: so how to check if [results4 valueForKey:@"error"] exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe add the json that is stored, it will be easier to help..

But what you should probably do is first check if there is a value for lets say :

```
          if([[results4 valueForKey:@"homeshort"] objectAtIndex:i ])
```

before you store it. or even better you can check for error :

```
           if([[results4 valueForKey:@"error"] isEqualToString: ""No live games found" ])
           { return; }
```

And return.

Hope this helps